# Timer starts only after the Form is closed

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, compact-framework2.0

I am currently working on a C# application that runs on a Windows CE 5 device with MS Compact Framework 2.0.
In this application I call a singleton dialog from a keyboard-hook asynchronously via BeginInvoke:

```
this.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate()
{
    DlgX.getInstance().display(TaskController.getInstance().getActiveTask().getValues(), true);
});
```

In the display method of the dialog I want to set the focus to a certain control. As the Win CE device is very slow, I have to use a timer to delay the Focus() execution:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer.Interval = 600;
timer.Enabled = true;
timer.Tick += (EventHandler)delegate(object obj, EventArgs args)
{
    button1.Focus();
    timer.Dispose();
};
```

Unfortunately this does not work. The timer gets executed as soon as I close the dialog.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for any help!

edit:
This is the whole display() method of the dialog:

```
public void display(List<InputRow> fvList, bool validate)
{
    this.fvList = fvList;
    ctlCount = (fvList.Count > 5 ? 5 : fvList.Count);
    for (int i = 0; i < ctlCount; i++)
    {
         //some 100% irrelevant stuff
    }
    button1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(btnOK_KeyDown);
    button1.Click += new EventHandler(btnOK_Click);
    if (!this.Visible)
    {
        ShowDialog();
    }
    if (validate)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 600;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Tick += (EventHandler)delegate(object obj, EventArgs args)
        {
            button1.Focus();
            timer.Dispose();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the event is fired when the form is closed ?
I suppose that this code is in `Form.Closing` ?
600 is in milliseconds, it seems normal that the event fires fast, have you tried to raise to something like 2s ?

Comment: I tried with an interval of 5000ms, the tick happened 5 seconds after I closed the dialog.
It gets executed in the display() method of the Form. I will edit the whole code of the display fnc into my post.

Comment: Does the debugger goes to you timer declaration ?
I think it gets stuck into `ShowDialog`, therefore preventing the launch of your timer. So your timer is launched after you close the dialog, it seems normal to me :o.
Or I didn't understood your problem..

Comment: Regrettably stepping through the code does not work with my Win CE 5 device.
But I tried to move the ShowDialog part after the timer - and now it works! Thank you very much for your help Luke :)

Comment: No problem ! Made an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timer instantiation and enabling is evaluated when you close your form, because `ShowDialog` is *synchronous*. You should put your timer before your `ShowDialog`